# Why is the lower bound in this binary search function the max value instead of the min?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code is the binary search function of a larger binary search problem.

My understanding was that the lower bounds should be the minimum value in a sorted array, and the upper bound should be the highest index(or max value). Why is `max()` and `sum()` being used in this case?

```
def binarySearch(A, max_block_cnt, M):
    lower_bound = max(A)
    upper_bound = sum(A)

    if max_block_cnt == 1:      return upper_bound
    if max_block_cnt >= len(A): return lower_bound

    while lower_bound <= upper_bound:
        candidate_mid = (lower_bound + upper_bound) // 2
        if blockSizeIsValid(A, max_block_cnt, candidate_mid):
            upper_bound = candidate_mid - 1
        else:
            lower_bound = candidate_mid + 1

    return lower_bound
```

This problem is the MinMaxDivision problem. Please let me know if more detail is needed.

Edit--appears more info needed. Here's the question I'm working on:

> You are given integers K, M and a non-empty
>   zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers. Every element of the
>   array is not greater than M.
>
> You should divide this array into K blocks of consecutive elements.
>   The size of the block is any integer between 0 and N. Every element of
>   the array should belong to some block.
>
> The sum of the block from X to Y equals A[X] + A[X + 1] + ... + A[Y].
>   The sum of empty block equals 0.
>
> The large sum is the maximal sum of any block.
>
> For example, you are given integers K = 3, M = 5 and array A such
>   that:
>
> A[0] = 2   A[1] = 1   A[2] = 5   A[3] = 1   A[4] = 2   A[5] = 2
>   A[6] = 2 The array can be divided, for example, into the following
>   blocks:
>
> [2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2], [], [] with a large sum of 15; [2], [1, 5, 1,
>   2], [2, 2] with a large sum of 9; [2, 1, 5], [], [1, 2, 2, 2] with a
>   large sum of 8; [2, 1], [5, 1], [2, 2, 2] with a large sum of 6. The
>   goal is to minimize the large sum. In the above example, 6 is the
>   minimal large sum.
>
> Write a function:
>
> def solution(K, M, A)
>
> that, given integers K, M and a non-empty zero-indexed array A
>   consisting of N integers, returns the minimal large sum.
>
> For example, given K = 3, M = 5 and array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 2   A[1] = 1   A[2] = 5   A[3] = 1   A[4] = 2   A[5] = 2
>   A[6] = 2 the function should return 6, as explained above.